# Cant access remote share in explorer if software is elevated uac (c++)

Tags: c++, admin, uac

I have a problem to access `network share drives` mapped in explorer from my software if it runs with administrator rights. 
If I disable `UAC` it runs well, so I can enumerate all network drives mapped in explorer.

My question is: How can I accesss this network drives or enumerate them when `UAC` is on?

I tried to change: `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` in registry, but it doesnt work.

Any solutions?

With kind regards
Xen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not UAC per se, nor is it running with administrator *rights*. The most likely problem is that you're running *under a different user account*. "Run As Administrator" will do that.

Each user account has its own network shares. When you're running as a different user, you will therefore enumerate different shares. Try running Explorer.EXE as that different user; you'll see that Explorer.EXE will then find the same shares as you do.

This is not easily worked around, by design. It's much harder for malware to spread when each user account can only access the drives and shares that it really needs.

The correct solution is probably not to run with UAC/Administrator rights. If you really, really need to, it's probably for one single administrative task. That task should be moved to a separate process, and only that process should be elevated. See for instance the clock app. That used to be able to show and change the time. But in modern Windows versions, changing the time is done by a separate elevated process.